# To include "kubectl get pods -n namespace" parameters in my custom dashboard

Tags: grafana

I have a custom dashboard in Grafana as below [CPU USAGE against PODS]

Pod CPU Usage   CPU Requests    CPU Requests %  CPU Limits  CPU Limits %
supersetapi-55995dcfdc-gxzdr    0.00    0.25    0.47%   0.50    0.23%
distributor-54569dcbff-457vx    0.01    0.25    2.90%   0.50    1.45%

I need to amend few details as below on to the aforesaid list

NAME                                READY   STATUS             RESTARTS   AGE
archiveentities-595dbdb4b7-zmnwm    1/2     InvalidImageName   0          24h
autoassign-649d454f59-2t577         2/2     Running            0          3h35m
autoassigndriver-6f9c85968c-dk7l2   2/2     Running            0          24h
autogrouping-8ffc9d46-7fx8j         2/2     Running            0          3h35m

could you please assist how to include "READY","STATUS","RESTARTS","AGE" in my custom dashboard[CPU USAGE against PODS] ?